# Add loading image until filtered layer is shown ol5

Tags: openlayers

I am developing a portal in which I have created a rectangle buffer and the polygon within buffer is selected. Here is my code to filter layer

```
var polyStyle = new ol.style.Style({  
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'green',
        width: 3
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
                text:("abcd"),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'red', width: 2
            }),
                font: font_size+'px Calibri,sans-serif',
            })
 });  
  var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
     style: function(feature) {
                  polyStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('KHASRA_NO'));
                  return polyStyle;

     }
 });
  map.addInteraction(select);
 var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();

cadLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({

          visible: true,
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function(extent) {
              $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                  service: 'WFS',
                  version: '1.1.0',
                  request: 'GetFeature',
                  typename: 'web_export:KHASRA_POLY1',
                   outputFormat: 'application/json',
                  srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                  bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
                }
              }).done(function(response) {
                console.log("response "+response);
                         features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);

                         // extent_swe=vectorSource.getExtent();
                        features = features.filter(function(el) {
                              if (jstsGeom.contains(parser.read(el.getGeometry()))) {
                                return true;
                              }
                            });
                            console.log("features "+features);
                             select.getFeatures().extend(features);
                            // vectorSource.addFeatures(features);

              });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all,
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
          }),
           style: new ol.style.Style({
                                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: 'yellow',
                                    width: 1
                                  }),
                                   opacity: 1, 
                                })
        }); 

            map.addLayer(cadLayer);
```

result image is
[image]

Now my problem is when layer is filtering it takes time to show result so that users don't know when result is shown.  I am thinking to add loading image so that user get to know result is coming.

How can I add loading image until result is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw an image on the canvas.  For demo purposes try this which adds a semi-transparent fill while the layer is loading.  If you have a suitable image use evt.context.drawImage instead.

```
var loading = false;
cadLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          visible: true,
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function(extent) {

              loading = true;
              $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {

                            ...
                            ...

              }).done(function(response) {

                            ...
                            ...

                            loading = false;
                             select.getFeatures().extend(features);
                            // vectorSource.addFeatures(features);

              });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all,
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
          }),


...
...

cadLayer.on('postcompose', function(evt){
  if (loading) {
    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
  }
});
map.addLayer(cadLayer);
```

If you use an image I suggest you load it as early as possible as it will load asynchronously.  If not same origin it must be CORS enabled.

```
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';  // only needed if not same origin
img.src = 'https://????/image.gif';
```

When you need to display it this will stretch the image across the canvas

```
cadLayer.on('postcompose', function(evt){
  if (loading) {
    evt.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
  }
});
```

You could animate the image yourself.  Set a start time when loading begins

```
          start = new Date().getTime();
          loading = true;
```

Then calculate the elapsed time when rendering.  In this case an image would move across the display at 200 pixels per seconds

```
cadLayer.on('postcompose', function(evt){
  if (loading) {
    var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    var x = (elapsed/5) % evt.context.canvas.width
    evt.context.drawImage(img, x, 0, img.width, img.height);
    map.render();
  }
});
```

Comment: it is showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in ol5.

Comment: That line should be after the end of the layer definition.  If you can add the layer to your map it must be defined.

Comment: oh my god. yes it is working. thanks a lot.

Comment: is gif image is working for this??

Comment: Yes, any file type which can be used in an image, but you would normally want png or gif because they support transparency.

Comment: gif image is not moving. it is just showing loading image.

Comment: It's same as icon style or static image, you can use any gif as the source and they are often used because they have transparency, but if it's an animated gif only the first frame is used.

Comment: A scrolling image would be easy, I've added that to the answer.